# AngularJS: Set element to class active by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I've created a custom tabbed element using the following code:

```
<div class="row step">
    <div class="col-md-4 arrow active" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.create.key_elements" ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }">
            <span class="number">1</span>
            <span class="h5">Key Elements</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 arrow" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.create.questions" ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }">
            <span class="number">2</span>
            <span class="h5">Questions</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 arrow" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.create.publish" ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }">
            <span class="number">3</span>
            <span class="h5">Publish</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm using ui-sref-active="active" to add a class of **active** to an element when it is clicked. My issue is getting the first element to display with a class of active when the page is *first* loaded as currently it only happens when an item is clicked. I've tried manually adding active to the first element but this seems to be ignored.

Comment: When you load the page, can you still see the active class in the first element?

Comment: Thanks @Sphaso. Doesn't seem to appear in the inspector tools

Comment: I think the issue is that, quite simply, the first element shouldn't be active if "dashboard.create.key_elements" is not the current route. See first example at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active
Maybe you want bootstrap "active"?

Comment: Thanks. Hope I've understood but have tried without a class of active on the first element and doesn't seem to change anything. I basically have some arrows that appear below and to the right of the active element

Comment: Ok, so it's a css problem. Can you use another class name for it? then for both "newclassname" and "active" you show the arrows? :)

Comment: Really appreciate your help @Spahso. I think that would have the effect of having "newclassname" as constantly active. I think my issue is that I'm trying to look for a quick fix to the existing markup whereas I should probably create a directive for the whole section

Comment: You're welcome, and you're absolutely right. I'm thinking of a more elegant solution, but at this point I think you could intercept the click and manage classes accordingly, using ng-click and ng-class? Basically you only need the ng-class for the first element. The others will use "active" to display the arrows

Comment: Yes I think that would be a better solution. Will try and implement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first route `dashboard.create.key_elements` is not the current route, so ui-router disables it as "active".

Solution:

1. Add another class in the CSS e.g. "newclassname" to have the same behavior of "active" class
2. Add ng-class to the first element conditioned to a variable in $scope and ng-click on the other elements so to disable it

In the JS:

```
$scope.firstActive = true;
$scope.changeFirst = function() {
      $scope.firstActive = false;
};
```

EDIT:

Better yet, instead of dabbling with ng-click, you can simply inject the variable when you define the routes. E.g. from a snippet of my own code

```
.state('ordini', {
            url: '/ordini/:pdv',
            templateUrl: 'ordini/ordini.html',
            controller: 'OrdiniController',
            resolve : {
                CartValue: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'CartService', function($rootScope, $stateParams, CartService){
                    return CartService.getCartValue($rootScope.user.MachCode, $stateParams.pdv);
                }]
            }
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the problem in question. The only issue I am having is that because I'm using ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }" the class persists when each of the elements is clicked. The reason for me using this is due to a calendar plugin (http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/) which doesn't reload with data whenever I change state and go back. With ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }" removed your solution works perfectly

Comment: Which class persists? "newclassname"?

Comment: Yes. ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }" causes ng-class="{newclassname: firstActive}" and $scope.firstActive = true; to be called again

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps move "$scope.firstActive" to $rootScope?

Comment: Oh god I'm such a moron. You can have a much more elegant solution by injecting a variable when you define the route. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction and for taking the time come up with the valuable solutions you've already provided! I'll have a more thorough look though this evening and hopefully will get it working :)